# Google Sign In fails with ApiException 10

Tags: android

All I'm trying to do is get access to Step count and distance walked in my Android app.

After trying several things based on several examples, I'm resigned to the idea that I have to ask the user to "Sign in with their Google account" in order for this to work.

So I tried that, and it doesn't work either. I keep getting "Google Sign In fails with ApiException 10". When I research this, all of the information talks about setting up some kind of OAuth key on Google Play.

My app isn't even IN Google Play yet. I'm just starting to work on it.

In addition, the app I'm working on isn't even ever going to BE in Google Play as-is. I'm working on some code that will eventually be given to another developer for integration into a larger app. The larger app already has its own accounts and sign-in screen. The users will be confused when the app asks them to sign in again.

I did the same thing in iOS a few weeks ago and there were no issues whatsoever other than a simple permissions request.

Am I missing something here, or is Android actually imposing all of this on me in order to do a simple function? Help!